# What does Wifi AP TP-Link PharOS "auto" channel/frequency setting?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

We have an outdoor wifi bridge using 2x TP-Link PharOS CPE610 V2, first in the AP mode, the other in Client mode.
The AP mode on a the building was setup by out partner to have the **channel/frequency** set to **auto**.
There is another wifi bridge (client) on the same building, which is Ubiquity M5 and has channel set to 128/5640 Mhz.

It happened sometimes, that the frequency on the PharOS AP changed to 128/5640 Mhz by itself and the TP-link wifi bridge went down. After restarting the PharOS AP the frequency changed to 100/5500 and bridge was up again and the client became visible.

[image: wifi]

Was it an error to setup the TP-Link PharOS AP channel to auto? Can the problem be fixed by setting channel to fixed 100/5500 Mhz? What does "auto" channel/frequency mean and what is the setting good for if it can lead to such problems?

In the [user quide](https://static.tp-link.com/2020/202004/20200430/1910012759_PharOS%20User%20Guide.pdf) there is nothing about the **auto** setting:

> Channel/FrequencySelect  appropriate  channel  used  by  this  device
> to  improve  wireless  performance.  1/2412  MHz  refers  to  Channel
> 1  and  the  frequency  is  2412  MHz.  This  setting  is  only
> available  in  Access  Point  Mode  and  AP  Router  Mode. We  highly
> recommend  that  you  use  the  Spectrum  Analysis  tool  to  select a
> proper channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auto usually means on a reboot the AP will scan the local environment for interference and move to the channel that it detects will be the clearest from neighboring interference.

These algorithm's used in consumer routers for channel selection don't usually work very well. For permanent links like bridges it should be disabled.

Not sure where you are living or the local regulations there, but channel 100 is a **Dynamic Frequency Selection** channel here in the U.S.

If you don't have the option to remove auto, that usually means you are on a DFS channel, and there is nothing you can do other than choose a static channel outside of the DFS range for the bridge links.

Comment: *move to the channel that it detects will be the clearest from neighboring interference* - but it did exactly the other way round - found the only occupied channel - like it was trying to adjust to the nearest client or AP.

Comment: Yea, the firmware auto selection is usually bad. For various reasons. Just set the channel to one with the least interference.